# react native Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native

Why I get this error ?

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

Code:

```
        {
          filterCategory && onDeleteCategory && filterCategory.length > 0 && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalCategory} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Kategorie</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteCategory} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
```

if I remove these one condition:

```
filterCategory
```

then it works. but not like the above first code. What I am doing wrong ? I only make a condition.

€: Full Code

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { globalStyles } from '../../shared/GlobalStyles'
import { DeleteIcon } from '../DeleteIcon'
import { IFilterTags } from './Model'

const FilterTags = ({
filterSize,
filterColor,
filterPrice,
filterCategory,
filterRating,
filterStatus,
onPressOpenModalSize,
onPressOpenModalColor,
onPressOpenModalPrice,
onPressOpenModalCategory,
onPressOpenModalRating,
onPressOpenModalStatus,
onDeleteSize,
onDeleteColor,
onDeletePrice,
onDeleteCategory,
onDeleteRating,
onDeleteStatus,
style
}: IFilterTags) => {
  const checkFilterCategory = () => filterCategory && onDeleteCategory && filterCategory.length > 0;
  return (
    <View style={[s.filterContainer, style]}>
        {
          filterSize && onDeleteSize && filterSize.length > 0 && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalSize} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Größe</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteSize} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
        {
         filterColor && onDeleteColor && filterColor.length > 0 && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalColor} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Farbe</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteColor} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
        {
          filterPrice && onDeletePrice && (filterPrice.from > 0 || filterPrice.to > 0) && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalPrice} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Preis</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeletePrice} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
        {
           onDeleteCategory && typeof filterCategory === 'string' && filterCategory.length > 0 && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalCategory} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Kategorie</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteCategory} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
        {
          filterRating && onDeleteRating && filterRating !== null && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalRating} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Bewertungen</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteRating} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
        {
         filterStatus && onDeleteStatus && filterStatus !== null && (
            <Pressable onPress={onPressOpenModalStatus} style={s.filterBtn}>
              <Text style={s.filterBtnText}>Zustand</Text>
              <DeleteIcon onPress={onDeleteStatus} iconSize={14} />
            </Pressable>
          )
        }
    </View>
  )
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  filterContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginTop: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 8
  },
  filterBtn: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#e5e5e5',
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  filterBtnText: {
    fontFamily: globalStyles.font_medium,
    color: globalStyles.globalColor
  }
})

export default FilterTags
```

the output of of the filterCategorie is only a emtpy string.

I am very thankful for your help.........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you show us the complete render function?

Comment: @DavidScholz yes look I edited

Comment: I have successfully compiled and rendered your code. There is no mistake in the code that you have shared. Your code might be different from the one that you have shared here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be no errors in your code at all.
React Native just "dont like" when we use more than one condition in conditional rendering.

You should wrap your conditions in circle brackets like this:

```
(filterCategory && onDeleteCategory && filterCategory.length > 0) &&
```

Btw, I suggest to use the optional chaining operator like so:

```
(onDeleteCategory && filterCategory?.length > 0) &&
```

Comment: This is false. Using conditional rendering with multiple conditions without parentheses is perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidScholz I suggest you to try conditional rendering with a condition like: someArray.length &&

    - In my tests, there are 0% chance that this will work fine. Maybe problem is that React wants boolean and gets number

Comment: It makes no difference what conditions we are using. Parentheses are not enforced. [Here is a snack to clear your doubts](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/rude-peanut).

Comment: @DavidScholz I got it!
Try to make array empty in your snack. Then make condition look like this: array.length &&    - It will render 0 as a TEXT. But in React Native you cant use View for text rendering. I chose IOS in snack and it crashed.

Comment: Yes, but then we do not have a "correct" conditional anymore. `array.length` is very different to `array.length > 0` and the questioner is not using a plain `array.length`.

Comment: To be precise, this is called a `falsy` expression and will cause the `&&` after the falsy expression to be skipped but it will also return the falsy expression.

Comment: In terms of rendering arrays of items, `array.length &&` and `array.length > 0 &&` looks equal for me. Why you think that first is falsy? If array isn't empty render will happen.

But I agree, the questioner is not using a plain `array.length`.

Comment: `array.length` is a so called `falsy` expression. If it returns `0` then it is considered `falsy` but it is not `false` (it is `0`). The expression `array.length > 0` is a valid boolean expression, it is `false` (not 0).  Booleans and null values are ignored by react, while falsy values are not. [this is documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

Comment: @DavidScholz Got it. I messed up `falsy` with `always false`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have Text outside of a Text tag. I know it sounds like I'm not really helping, but believe me, this happens often in RN. You must have spaces somewhere. You should use some linting tool like ESLint.

But for now, just check spaces, try removing components until you found where is the issue and check character by character. There's something there, you are just not seeing it.